# Can I set full height bar background color in Echarts.js?

Tags: javascript, echarts

[image: Background placeholder color in bar chart]

Can I set bar full height default background color in echarts.js like the attached image? I searched the options from their documentation [Echarts bar documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar) but unfortunately I couldn't find it. Please help me. by which option I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add to series `showBackground: true` like in example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-background